# Resolving TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I've tried researching this issue, but it appears like the causes for it can be varied and would like some input.  The following line;

```
resultRisport70 = clientRisport70.service.selectCmDevice('','CmSelectionCriteria'({'SelectBy':'Name','Status':'Any','DeviceClass':'Phone','SelectItems':{'item':{'Item':'SEPblah'}}}))
```

Incurs the error;

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I've tried restructuring the line, but I can't seem to figure out the issue.  I also have a similarly stuctured line in python2 which seems to work, but this one in python3 does run.  Any help is appreciated.

I have the same type code, written in php;

```
$devices1 = $soapClient->selectCmDevice(array(
        'StateInfo' => '',
        'CmSelectionCriteria'=>
        (array(
            'DeviceClass'=>'Phone',
            'SelectBy'=>'Name',
            'Status'=>'Registered',
            'Protocol'=>'Any',
            'DownloadStatus'=>'Any',
            'SelectItems'=>array(
                'item'=>array(
                    'Item'=>'*' . $searchString . '*'
                ))))));
```

Here is a version of the same code, going to a depracted WSDL, but seems to work fine;

```
resultRisport70 = clientRisport70.service.SelectCmDevice('',{'SelectBy':'Name', 'Status':'Registered', 'Class':'Phone','SelectItems':{'SelectItem':{'Item':phoneDetailName}}})
```

Comment: What is `'CmSelectionCriteria'(...)` supposed to do?

Comment: Maybe remove the quotes around 'CmSelectionCriteria'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to call a string as a function here, and that isn't possible. Specifically,

`'CmSelectionCriteria'()`

Isn't valid.

`"abc"()` causes the same error. You can't execute a call on a string.

If CmSelectionCriteria is a function you have defined somewhere else, remove the quotes.

Comment: Please see update, I've included the same thing but written in PHP (which works).

Comment: When you remove the quotation marks around that function call (CmSelectionCriteria), do you get ```NameError: name 'CmSelectionCriteria' is not defined```??? As for PHP, syntax is different. Python's ```()``` is going to make a call (presumably a function or method), and ```'CmSelectionCriteria'``` is a string, so, any ```()``` at the end of it will make a call on the string. But strings themselves are not callable (they do have methods, like ```str.lower()``` but are not callable in of themselves.

Comment: So that means you have not defined the function CmSelectionCriteria in the python code.

Comment: This code is working with a WSDL, where it has been defined.  In the PHP version (see original post), it works fine.

Comment: You would need to define it somewhere with 
```
def CmSelectionCriteria():
    <insert function logic here>
```

Comment: If you are getting ```NameError: name 'CmSelectionCriteria' is not defined``` it is because the interpreter does not have access to that function. Doesn't matter where it IS defined, but whether Python interpreter has access to it.

Comment: But I've not worked with WSDL sorry. Perhaps time for a different question. As for your original question, this is the correct answer.

Comment: Hey matisetorm, I've added to the original post the same code going to an older WSDL (which has been deprecated, hence my situation), this seems to work fine and I didn't need to define anything.

Comment: I notice that in the code you added you do call the ```SelectCmDevice``` function but not the ```CmSelectionCriteria``` function. Which would explain why it the added code is working but the original is not. Again,```CmSelectionCriteria``` is not defined or availible to your python interpreter.  I did a few google searches and saw someone create the selection criteria manually. That may allow you to execute without having to call ```CmSelectionCriteria``` https://communities.cisco.com/thread/77504?start=0&tstart=0

Please accept answer. We have moved beyond the original question :)